# MongoDB replication RAM usage

Tags: mongodb

I have two production servers running Windows server 2012 R2. As a primary and secondary server, they are used for a failover scenario, where the if one fails, the other will take the load.

My application is using MongoDB replication. I have 3 instances. Primary and arbiter (which i'm going to move it on a different server, this is just a temporary souliton) and a secondary node on the secondary server.

After a time, the RAM consumption is becoming very high on both servers. MongoDB takes all the available RAM usage and does not release it. I have noted this behavior only when the MongoDB is working in a replica.

I have done some research, and found out that it is not possible to limit the RAM usage of the mongod process itself. I'm little skeptic with MongoDB using all the RAM.

Please share your experiences, thoughts or ideas how to limit the RAM usage of the mongodb process on my windows server.

Comment: Can you post the output of `db.serverStatus()` and `rs.status()` from the mongo shell? How are you measuring the memory usage of MongoDB on Windows?

Comment: hi @wdberkeley, please find my comment below.

As per measuring the memory usage I use windows resource monitor, and zabbix

Answer (score 0):

How much memory do your servers have? Are they hitting the swap file? Remember that Mongo uses memory-mapped files, which can make it look like it's using much more RAM than it really is at any given time.

That being said, you should always be trying to ensure that your RAM is large enough to hold Mongo's working set (that is, the data it's constantly, simultaneously using). If it isn't, your performance will degrade sharply.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer :)

My servers have 32 GB of RAM each. The database that the application is using is only 200 megabytes.

I haven't let the mongo reach 32 GB. When it comes to 29-30 gigabytes I do a restart off the process on both servers so the memory can be released. I do this every 3 days, which is unacceptable.

So I do not know if it is using the swap or not. I'm not letting him hit the max.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output requested:

```
    /* 0 */
    {
"host" : "XXXXXXX",
"version" : "2.6.3",
"process" : "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\\bin\\mongod.exe",
"pid" : NumberLong(4216),
"uptime" : 162370,
"uptimeMillis" : NumberLong(162369902),
"uptimeEstimate" : 103914,
"localTime" : ISODate("2014-10-07T12:40:28.379Z"),
"asserts" : {
    "regular" : 0,
    "warning" : 0,
    "msg" : 0,
    "user" : 37,
    "rollovers" : 0
},
"backgroundFlushing" : {
    "flushes" : 2705,
    "total_ms" : 4260795,
    "average_ms" : 1575.155268022181,
    "last_ms" : 1531,
    "last_finished" : ISODate("2014-10-07T12:40:07.363Z")
},
"connections" : {
    "current" : 11,
    "available" : 999989,
    "totalCreated" : NumberLong(11240)
},
"cursors" : {
    "note" : "deprecated, use server status metrics",
    "clientCursors_size" : 1,
    "totalOpen" : 1,
    "pinned" : 0,
    "totalNoTimeout" : 12,
    "timedOut" : 0
},
"dur" : {
    "commits" : 22,
    "journaledMB" : 0.114688,
    "writeToDataFilesMB" : 0.53375,
    "compression" : 0.2144153811926631,
    "commitsInWriteLock" : 0,
    "earlyCommits" : 0,
    "timeMs" : {
        "dt" : 3093,
        "prepLogBuffer" : 0,
        "writeToJournal" : 4,
        "writeToDataFiles" : 0,
        "remapPrivateView" : 0
    }
},
"extra_info" : {
    "note" : "fields vary by platform",
    "page_faults" : 67893258,
    "usagePageFileMB" : 471,
    "totalPageFileMB" : 37631,
    "availPageFileMB" : 29647,
    "ramMB" : 32767
},
"globalLock" : {
    "totalTime" : NumberLong(162369902000),
    "lockTime" : NumberLong(1427273211),
    "currentQueue" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "readers" : 0,
        "writers" : 0
    },
    "activeClients" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "readers" : 0,
        "writers" : 0
    }
},
"indexCounters" : {
    "accesses" : 2950266,
    "hits" : 2950266,
    "misses" : 0,
    "resets" : 0,
    "missRatio" : 0
},
"locks" : {
    "." : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "R" : NumberLong(15503628),
            "W" : NumberLong(1427273211)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "R" : NumberLong(83884262),
            "W" : NumberLong(11591779)
        }
    },
    "admin" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(1713001),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(722033),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "local" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(44889906),
            "w" : NumberLong(1701164461)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(714690116),
            "w" : NumberLong(210449023)
        }
    },
    "XXXXX" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(856843350),
            "w" : NumberLong(2135956163)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(1178898843),
            "w" : NumberLong(99380013)
        }
    }
},
"network" : {
    "bytesIn" : 14159238584,
    "bytesOut" : 180594998456,
    "numRequests" : 5238602
},
"opcounters" : {
    "insert" : 619,
    "query" : 2089612,
    "update" : 1552936,
    "delete" : 737,
    "getmore" : 483165,
    "command" : 1200862
},
"opcountersRepl" : {
    "insert" : 0,
    "query" : 0,
    "update" : 0,
    "delete" : 0,
    "getmore" : 0,
    "command" : 0
},
"recordStats" : {
    "accessesNotInMemory" : 1137889,
    "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 153,
    "XXXXX" : {
        "accessesNotInMemory" : 1194,
        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 153
    },
    "admin" : {
        "accessesNotInMemory" : 2,
        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
    },
    "local" : {
        "accessesNotInMemory" : 1136693,
        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
    }
},
"repl" : {
    "setName" : "XXXXX",
    "setVersion" : 18,
    "ismaster" : true,
    "secondary" : false,
    "hosts" : [ 
        "10.246.5.221:3000", 
        "10.246.5.222:3000"
    ],
    "arbiters" : [ 
        "10.246.5.221:3001"
    ],
    "primary" : "10.246.5.221:3000",
    "me" : "10.246.5.221:3000"
},
"writeBacksQueued" : false,
"mem" : {
    "bits" : 64,
    "resident" : 13184,
    "virtual" : 91002,
    "supported" : true,
    "mapped" : 45402,
    "mappedWithJournal" : 90804
},
"metrics" : {
    "cursor" : {
        "timedOut" : NumberLong(0),
        "open" : {
            "noTimeout" : NumberLong(12),
            "pinned" : NumberLong(0),
            "total" : NumberLong(1)
        }
    },
    "document" : {
        "deleted" : NumberLong(1430),
        "inserted" : NumberLong(619),
        "returned" : NumberLong(19561957),
        "updated" : NumberLong(1553197)
    },
    "getLastError" : {
        "wtime" : {
            "num" : 0,
            "totalMillis" : 0
        },
        "wtimeouts" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    "operation" : {
        "fastmod" : NumberLong(315457),
        "idhack" : NumberLong(0),
        "scanAndOrder" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    "queryExecutor" : {
        "scanned" : NumberLong(1551879),
        "scannedObjects" : NumberLong(1551879)
    },
    "record" : {
        "moves" : NumberLong(773)
    },
    "repl" : {
        "apply" : {
            "batches" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalMillis" : 0
            },
            "ops" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "buffer" : {
            "count" : NumberLong(0),
            "maxSizeBytes" : 268435456,
            "sizeBytes" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "network" : {
            "bytes" : NumberLong(0),
            "getmores" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalMillis" : 0
            },
            "ops" : NumberLong(0),
            "readersCreated" : NumberLong(11)
        },
        "preload" : {
            "docs" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalMillis" : 0
            },
            "indexes" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalMillis" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "storage" : {
        "freelist" : {
            "search" : {
                "bucketExhausted" : NumberLong(0),
                "requests" : NumberLong(2713),
                "scanned" : NumberLong(2966)
            }
        }
    },
    "ttl" : {
        "deletedDocuments" : NumberLong(0),
        "passes" : NumberLong(2705)
    }
},
"ok" : 1
```

}

```
rs.status():
    /* 0 */
    {
"set" : "XXXX",
"date" : ISODate("2014-10-07T12:42:34.000Z"),
"myState" : 1,
"members" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "xx.xxx.x.xxx:3000",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        "uptime" : 162496,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1412685754, 24),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-10-07T12:42:34.000Z"),
        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1412523277, 1),
        "electionDate" : ISODate("2014-10-05T15:34:37.000Z"),
        "self" : true
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "name" : "xx.xxx.x.xxx:3001",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 7,
        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
        "uptime" : 162485,
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-10-07T12:42:33.000Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-10-07T12:42:33.000Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "name" : "yy.yyy.y.yyy:3000",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 162482,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1412685752, 24),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-10-07T12:42:32.000Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-10-07T12:42:33.000Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-10-07T12:42:33.000Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0,
        "syncingTo" : "xx.xxx.x.xx:3000"
    }
],
"ok" : 1
   }
```